# Can the same function be called again when the value of the function parameter changes after the program is run in C #?

Tags: c#

I have a file named tempdate.txt inside the folder named temp. This tempdate.txt contains  a value as hour.minute.second format. For example, my application takes data from tempdate.txt file as 14.25.23 and runs a function. However, after the application was running, I changed the 14.25.23 data in tempdate.txt to 15.23.12. Can I catch this change in tempdate.txt file in  my C # application after the program runs and run another function according to this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a class called [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netcore-3.1) which you can use to watch specific files/directories and perform some action on change.

Comment: Thank you. I'll search and come back again.

Comment: The other option is to poll the directory periodically for fileinfo and just cache the previous values to compare against. `FileSystemWatcher` works fine but can have issues if a lot of changes happen in the directory at once and overflow the internal buffer. Something to be aware of.

Comment: I see what you are talking about. However, I did not have a problem in my project as there would not be such frequent changes in the file. I achieved the result I wanted with FileSystemwatcher , thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with configuration values that can change during runtime, the convention in dotnetcore is to add an appsettings.json file and configure the generic host to reload the file on change.

This does require a bit of knowledge of IOptionsMonitor, dependency injection, and object oriented programming to get wired up but it is the more industry standard solution.

Comment: I'm not that experienced at the moment but thank you for your help. I achieved the result I wanted.